# Calculate distance matrix based on network

Tags: pyqgis, distance-matrix, network-analysis

I have the following layers in QGIS:

- origins points
- destination points
- a layer of lines that is the route

I want to calculate the matrix with the distance from origin to destination using [Network Analysis](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/network_analysis.html).

I've tried to do a python script using [this](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/network_analysis.html), but I'm not seeing any results.

I honestly do not know anything about gis or python. But I need to make a data analysis. This is what I have done, I can not even read the layers.
I'm also not sure if the cost represents the distance traveled

```
#Definition of inputs and outputs
#==================================
##[my scripts]=group
##origin_layer=vector
##origin_id_column_index=field origin_layer
##destination_layer=vector
##destination_id_column_index=field destination_layer
##route_layer=vector
##output=string 

#Algorithm body
#==================================


from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.networkanalysis import *

from processing.core.VectorWriter import VectorWriter
import processing 
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt


origin_layer = processing.getObject(origin_layer)
origin_id_column_index = origin_layer.fieldNameIndex(origin_id_column_index)


destination_layer = processing.getObject(destination_layer)
destination_id_column_index = destination_layer.fieldNameIndex(destination_id_column_index)


route_layer = processing.getObject(route_layer)



# don't use information about road direction from layer attributes,
# all roads are treated as two-way
director = QgsLineVectorLayerDirector(route_layer, -1, '', '', '', 3)


for origin_feature in origin_layer:
    pStart = origin_feature.geometry().centroid().asPoint()
    for destination_feature in destination_layer:
        pStop = destination_feature.geometry().centroid().asPoint()
        tiedPoints = director.makeGraph(builder, [pStart, pStop])
        graph = builder.graph()
        tStart = tiedPoints[0]
        tStop = tiedPoints[1]
        idStart = graph.findVertex(tStart)
        idStop = graph.findVertex(tStop)
        (tree, cost) = QgsGraphAnalyzer.dijkstra(graph, idStart, 0)
```

Comment: Since you don't know programming, have you considered a different approach, such as https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228949/qgis-least-cost-distance-points-to-destinations-via-roads?rq=1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find the solution

```
#Definition of inputs and outputs
#==================================
##[my scripts]=group
##origin_layer=vector
##origin_id_column_index=field origin_layer
##destination_layer=vector
##destination_id_column_index=field destination_layer
##route_layer=vector
##outpath=string 

#Algorithm body
#==================================


from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.networkanalysis import *

from processing.core.VectorWriter import VectorWriter
import processing 
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt


origin_layer = processing.getobject(origin_layer)

origin_id_column_index = origin_layer.fieldNameIndex(origin_id_column_index)


destination_layer = processing.getobject(destination_layer)

destination_id_column_index = destination_layer.fieldNameIndex(destination_id_column_index)

route_layer = processing.getobject(route_layer)



# don't use information about road direction from layer attributes,
# all roads are treated as two-way


file = open(outpath + 'matrizDistancia.csv','w')
file.write( 'indexGenerador, indexRecolector, distancia\n')



for origin_feature in origin_layer.getFeatures():
    pStart = origin_feature.geometry().centroid().asPoint()
    indexGenerador = origin_feature.attributes()[origin_id_column_index]
    for destination_feature in destination_layer.getFeatures():
        director = QgsLineVectorLayerDirector(route_layer, -1, '', '', '', 3)
        properter = QgsDistanceArcProperter()
        director.addProperter( properter )
        builder = QgsGraphBuilder( route_layer.crs() )
        #aca empieza a itrear
        pStop = destination_feature.geometry().centroid().asPoint()
        indexRecolector = destination_feature.attributes()[destination_id_column_index]
        tiedPoints = director.makeGraph(builder, [pStart, pStop])
        graph = builder.graph()
        tStart = tiedPoints[0]
        tStop = tiedPoints[1]
        idStart = graph.findVertex(tStart)
        idStop = graph.findVertex(tStop)
        (tree, cost) = QgsGraphAnalyzer.dijkstra(graph, idStart, 0)
        file.write( '{0}, {1}, {2}\n'.format(indexGenerador, indexRecolector, cost[idStop]))
file.close()
```